# Align arrows with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I want to write with `tikz-cd` a map, in such a way that the two arrows are aligned and have the same length. I got this by adding `\phantom{}` everywhere, but I wonder if there's a easier (smarter) way.

My attemp:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = 0ex]
\tau : I \arrow[rightarrow]{r} & \mathbb{R} \phantom{---------} \\
\phantom{\tau :. }  t \arrow[mapsto]{r} & \tau (t) := \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t} \sqrt{T \cdot T} \ \mathrm{d} s
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you *need* `tikz-cd` for that display to begin with?

Comment: @egreg I suppose I do not need `tikz-cd` precisely (though I would like), I just thought it was a good tool. What I need is to write maps, in that way.

Comment: `\begin{aligned}\tau\colon I &\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\\ t&\longmapsto \tau(t)...\end{aligned}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `tikz-cd`, but also with a simpler `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep = 0ex,
  /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east},
  /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west},
]
\tau\colon I \arrow[r] & \mathbb{R} \\
t \arrow[r,mapsto] & \tau (t) := \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t} \sqrt{T \cdot T} \diff s
\end{tikzcd}

$\begin{aligned}
\tau\colon I & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
t & \longmapsto \tau (t) := \int_{t_0}^{t} \sqrt{T \cdot T} \diff s
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An `align*` environment will be much more flexible. B.t.w., you should use `\colon`, not `:` for a better spacing, and `\coloneqq` (from `mathtools`), as in `:=` the colon is not centred on the maths axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = 0ex]
  τ: I \arrow[rightarrow]{r} & \mathbb{R} \phantom{---------} \\
  \phantom{τ:. } t \arrow[mapsto]{r} & τ(t) := \displaystyle ∫_{t₀}^{t} √{T · T} \ \mathrm{d} s
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{align*}
  τ\colon I & ―――→ \mathbb{R} & τ\colon I & \xrightarrow{\qquad} \mathbb{R} \\[-1ex]
  t & \longmapsto τ(t) ∶= ∫_{t₀}^{t} √{T · T} \, \mathrm{d} s & t & \xmapsto{\qquad} τ(t) ∶= ∫_{t₀}^{t} √{T · T} \, \mathrm{d} s
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]